# I get nan values in chisquare test

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I removed complete nan values in my dataset and checking whether two features are independent or dependent using chisquare test.But I am getting null values

```
t1=pd.crosstab(df['Scheduled Delivery Date'],df['Product Group']).values
stats.chisquare(f_obs=t1,ddof=7084)
```

Result:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=array([ 3306.5       ,  2394.36363636, 13689.2797075 ,  4967.26974144,        1767.        ]), pvalue=array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]))
```

How to get p value without nan using scipy.stats.chisquare?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems:

- You have used [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to compute a frequency table (also known as a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)), but you then pass that table to [`scipy.stats.chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html), which operates on a 1-d data set.  When given a 2-d table, `scipy.stats.chisquare` applies the chi-square test to each column of the table, which is not what you want.  You say you want to check the independence of two features, so the function that you should use is [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).
- You used `ddof=7084`, but `ddof` is the *delta* degrees of freedom; i.e. it is an increment or decrement to the default value.  It is unlikely that 7084 is the correct value to use here.   (With `chi_contingency`, the degrees of freedom is computed for you.)

So your code should probably be

```
t1 = pd.crosstab(df['Scheduled Delivery Date'], df['Product Group']).values
result = stats.chi2_contingency(t1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my doubt, While I use scipy.stats.chi2_contingency, I am getting pvalue exactly 0.0 or 1.0 for some features, Is this issue with scipy library

Comment: It is probably an issue (or non-issue!) with your data. p-values as low as 0 or as high as 1 are possible.  For example,  the table `np.array([[750, 0], [0, 750]])` gives a p-value of 0.0, while the table `np.array([[10, 11, 12], [10, 11, 12]])` gives a p-value of 1.0.